# Convert String into Date With Locale

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a date as a string like "2014-01-01 00:00:00". I want to convert it into Date With EST Local and my application server is in IST.

So my expected output when I print date would be **"Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2014"**.

But it resulted output is **"Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2014"**.

Below is my code.

```
    DateFormat formatter;
    Date formattedDate = null;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    try
    {
        formattedDate = formatter.parse("01-01-2014 00:00:00");
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

How can I get my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `parse`, execute that method:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    String convertedDate = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    try {
        Date date1 = formatter.parse(convertedDate);
        System.out.println("IST : "+date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I want a date object as returned not string.Cause after that i have to  convert that date into another timezone.

Comment: Time is different.I want same time only the difference will be in IST or EST.date and time should be same.

Comment: Actually time difference will be there because you are changing zone

Comment: yes but i dont want .. actually in my application,we wil get date string from client side and then we are converting it into GMT,so basically if date is "2014/04/21" and client is in EST timezone then date should be converted into GMT according to that timezone.

Comment: You are abit confused i think it is the same time being converted to different zone time value what you trying to say i'm not able to understand can you give some example

Comment: In my application,I have search field of date like date from and date To,and user which uses application can have EST timezone or IST timezone.Now if he searches with "2014/04/21" from IST timezone then the date should be converted into GMT according to that and if he searches with same date from EST timezone then the date should be converted into GMT format according to that.then I need to compare that in database.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2014-01-01 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
```

## Details

The Question and other Answers use outdated legacy classes.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we must parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

To parse, we can make the input string comply strictly with the ISO 8601 standard format by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2014-01-01 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

Now assign this value a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

By `EST` perhaps you meant the east coast of the US, `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneID );
```

## Locale vs Time zone

The title of this Question refers to Locale.

Do not confuse that with time zone. Time zone refers to an offset-from-UTC plus a set of rules for handling that region’s particular anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). A Locale specifies (a) a human language for use in translating name of day and name of month, and (b) cultural norms for deciding issues such as lowercase/uppercase, abbreviations, punctuation, and order of parts.

The two issues, time zone and locale, are orthogonal, distinct and unrelated. You can have a French locale used for an Indian time zone, or a Moroccan locale used for New Zealand time zone. The time zone affects the meaning of the data while locale affects only its presentation as a String.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.GERMANY );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

If the cases of both locale and time zone, if omitted then your JVM’s current default will be applied implicitly. That default can vary. Better to always specify explicitly your desired/expected locale and your desired/expected time zone.